# codeigniter site keeps redirecting in a loop

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

I did some researches on the net and on stackoverflow but none of the solution presented didn't helped me.I have a website running on codeigniter and it was running up on the server for about a year now.All of the sudden the website stopped working and the browser presented the following error message: too many redirects occurred trying to open "www.test.com". The files weren't modified during the last year, so this happened suddenly. I actually don't know at what to look because is the first time I encountered such an error. I moved the files in a subfolder, made the changes in the config file to follow the subdirectory path. If i call the subdirectory the site is loading but if I hit refresh the site is getting me back to the main domain. ex: if i call www.domain.ro/subdomain after refresh it takes me back to www.domain.ro . The structure of my config file is the following:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://www.chorusengineering.ro/backupnew";
$config['site_name'] = "Chorus Engineering";
$config['folder'] = "/";
$config['mailchimp_key'] = '76b134d27c0ac5c692220f35fbaa9c27-us7';
$config['mailchimp_list_id'] = '81054767d3';
$config['index_page'] = "http://www.chorusengineering.ro/backupnew";
```

The route is set to the default controller that I want to load:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "main";
```

I deleted the htacces file. None of the solutions I found on the internet helped me. Please a little help because this is getting very frustrating.

And my index function is:

```
function index(){
        $seo = array(
             'section' => 'homepage',
             'p_key' => '__',
             'p_key_value' => '__'
        );

        $data['wdx'] = $this->mdl_wdx->get_general('_main/index.php', $seo);
        $data['page'] = $this->m_core->get_one_record(1, 'id');
        $data['_is_home'] = TRUE;

        $data['news'] = $this->news->get_featured();
        $data['slider'] = $this->sliders->get_slider();
        //$data['slider_evenimente'] = $this->news->get_slider();
        $data['articles'] = $this->articles->get_featured();

        $this->load->view('_layout_home', $data);
    }//end index()
```

Comment: do a force redirect on your index function in the controller to transfer to the new url

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: in your main controller there should be a function called `index` you can add a `redirect(base_url() . 'Controller/somewhere');`

Comment: see my updated question